# Why does the error keep stating incompatible integer to pointer in C for an array?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, binary-search, cs50

I'm making a binary search and I don't know if it's a problem with my recursion statement or if I'm not using the array correctly, but I can't figure out the problem.
The error keep prompting me to add an '&' sign in front of nValues in the recursion statement, which I also don't understand.

```
#include <cs50.h>

#include "helpers.h"

/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */

bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    if (n < 0) //return 0 if negative
        return 0;
    else
    {
        if(values[(int)(n/2)] == value) //if value is found return true
            return 1;
        else if(value < values[(int)(n/2)]) //if value is less than middle, search bottom half
        {
            int nValues[(int)(n/2)-1]; //make an array of size bottom half
            for(int i = 0; i < (int)n/2; i++) //put in bottom half into a new array
            {
                nValues[i] = values[i];
            }
            search(value, nValues[(int)(n/2)-1], (int)(n/2)-1); //recursion with bottom half of the array
        }
        else if(value >values[(int)(n/2)]) //if higher than middle, search upper half
        {
            int nValues[(int)(n/2)+1]; //make an array of size upper half
            for(int i = (int)(n/2); i< n; i++) //iterate through the top half to create new array 
            {
                nValues[i] = values[i]; 
            }
            search(value, nValues[(int)(n/2)+1], (int)(n/2)); //recursion with upper half of the array
        }

    }
    return 0; //if all fails, return false

}
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: Casting `n` to `(int)` is pointless. `n` is already an `int`.

Comment: I don't think this expression `int nValues[(int)(n / 2) - 1];` is legal in C

Comment: Not exactly on topic but why have you got 2 `for` loops in there? Binary search can be more neat to look at.

Comment: @SimoneCifani It's a declaration, not an expression.

Comment: `search(value, nValues[(int)(n/2)-1],` --> `search(value, nValues,`. Also `if (n < 0)` --> `if (n <= 0)`

Comment: `int nValues[(int)(n/2)+1];` --> `int nValues[n - (n / 2 + 1)];`

Comment: @melpomene There isn't an error message when it compiles, it just goes to segmentation fault.

Comment: @JMinow your question lacks a [MCVE](/help/mcve); a minimal complete and verifiable example!

Comment: You don't need to make a copy of the bottom or top half of the array. Just pass a pointer to the beginning of the half you want, with the appropriately reduced length.

Comment: `for(int i = (int)(n/2); i< n; i++){ nValues[i] = values[i]; }` --> `for(int i = 0, k = n / 2 + 1; k < n; i++, k++){ nValues[i] = values[k]; }`

Comment: `int nValues[(int)(n/2)-1];` --> `int nValues[n / 2];`

Comment: `search(` --> `return search(`

Comment: @JMinow Then why does your question ask about an error? "*Why does the error keep stating ...*"  "*The error keep prompting me ...*"

Comment: @melpomene originally the error was "helpers.c:39:34: error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'int *'; take the address with &
            return search(value, nValues[n/2], (n/2));

Comment: type of `nValues[n/2]` is `int`. You need to pass the array or the first address of the array. E.g `nValues` or `&nValues[0]`

Comment: Never use a cast if you don't need it or don't understand what the cast actually does.

Comment: fix like [this](http://ideone.com/c6SYH0)

Comment: Doesn't use `nValues` [ver.](http://ideone.com/lZ1an8)

Comment: Doesn't use recursion [ver.](http://ideone.com/2jSe7R)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the phrasing of your question, I'm guessing that you are unfamiliar with the concept of pointers. In C, pointer is a type that stores the memory address of another variable. The `&` operator retrieves the memory address of a variable.

```
int i = 4;    // < An integer variable equal to 4
int* ip = &i; // < A pointer variable equal to the memory address of i
```

In C, arrays are handled as pointers to the first (0th) element of the array.

```
int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
a == &a[0] // The name of the array is the same as the address of the first element
```

The confusion you're having arises from the double-use of the `[]` operator. When used as a declaration, `[]` means a pointer (because arrays are the same as pointers). When used in an expression, `[]` accesses an element of an array.

Your method declaration asks for a parameter `int values[]` which, because it's a declaration, means a pointer to an `int`. In your recursive call, you supply the argument `nValues[(int)(n/2)+1]` which, because it's an expression, accesses the `(n/2)+1`th element of the array, which is an `int`, NOT a pointer to an `int`.

As a side note, `n` is an integer and `2` is an integer, so `n/2` will also be an integer. There's no reason to cast it.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! I just made a recursive helper function with a start and end as parameters and iterated through the array.